# Why is this not rejecting my records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  >> a
  => [6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
  >> @project.posts(:all, :conditions => [ "id not in (?)", a ])
  => [#<Post id: 6,........
```

Why is this not filtering the POst with id of 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `@project.posts.find(:all, :conditions => .....)`. The method call of just the association itself takes one parameter which indicates whether to reload the association or not.